# Difference in cardinality of arranged subsets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that for any nonempty set, we can put its subsets in a row, so that any two neighboring subsets differ on their cardinality by $1$.

Here is my attempt on this:

Let the nonempty set be $S$. We use induction on the $|S|$.

For the base case, $|S|=1$, it only has one subset, which is $S$ itself, so the statement is clearly true.

For the inductive step, we need to prove that the condition is true for $n+1$ given that it is true for $n$. When we append the element $n+1$ to $S$,  then the new subsets formed are all of the subsets before along with $n+1$ appended to them.

Now, I'm not sure where to go from here. Could someone please help?

Comment: If $|S|=1$, then $S$ has two subsets, $S$ and $\varnothing$. Fortunately, they differ by just one element.

Comment: How does your approach work with infinite sets?

Answer (score 1):

**Sketch**. Take any $a \in S$ and arrange the subsets as follows: first arrange the subsets of $S \setminus \{ a \}$ in a sequence using the induction hypothesis. Then write the same sequence backwards, appending $a$ to each subset. The two sequences one after another form the desired arrangement.

By the way, the resulting construction is known as the [Gray code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code).

Comment: Why are you writing the sequence backwards? Why not forwards?

Comment: @CoolMath200 The "backwards" ensures that the last subset in the first (forward) half and the first subset in the second (backward) half differ by only one element, $a$.